# I have a boto3 lambda function which uses table.scan to scan the dynamoDB. I want to send limited data to frontend to show 10 entries, cant use query

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want someone to help me with how to implement pagination in boto3 without query, NextToken. I want the dynamoDB data to be sent to the frontend but 10 entries at a time and every time send the next 10 entries to the frontend.
First I thought I could use the query but the primary key would filter most of the data and I want all the results, just 10 entries at a time.
Also on the frontend, it has to be like page1(10 entries), page2(next 10 ) , like that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct approach from what I'm getting your question.

Above mentioned approach by Mark B is good but not for your case you won't be able to move to any page other than next or  go to previous page directly with this approach.

You can implement a not so cost efficient approach by adding a field to db of page number and using a lambda function to maintain pagination in db

Answer (score 1):

To implement pagination with a DynamoDB scan operation you have to save the `LastEvaluatedKey` value that was returned from the first scan, and pass that as the `ExclusiveStartKey` on the next scan.

On the first scan operation (`page == 0`) you would simply pass `Limit=10` in the query parameters.

On the second scan operation (`page == 1`) you would pass `Limit=10, ExclusiveStartKey=<lastScanResult.LastEvaluatedKey>`.

Note that you will have to pass the `LastEvaluatedKey` value to the frontend as part of your result data, the frontend will have to store that in memory, and send it as part of the request data when it requests the next page.

Comment: actually, I want to be able to go to any desired page and your solution only allows me to go to the next one and the previous one.

Comment: @Utkarsh what you want isn't possible to do in DynamoDB.